# "LNK1104: cannot open file 'X'": How to find out who wants X linked in?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

Okay, I'm stumped. I'm fiddling with some project settings, trying to start linking against library *Y* instead of library *X*.  When I search through the project file (`.vcproj`) and all the inherited property sheets (`.vsprops`), there are no references left to library *X*. I've closed and reopened Visual Studio to make sure it's not holding onto some old version of the project. However, as suggested by the title, I still get the link error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'X'
```

When I come across this sort of problem with header files (not knowing what file is including that header), I usually rename the problem header to cause a `C1083: Cannot open include file` error, which tells me what source file is requesting it. But here the `LNK1104` is not nearly as useful. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can track this down? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under project settings / linker / general there's a setting called "show progress", if you set it to "/VERBOSE" the linker will show you all kinds of stuff including the "/DEFAULTLIB" items it finds.  This can be helpful, depending on whether the import is coming from a lib file, or not.

You should also search your solution source code for a "#pragma comment(lib,...", which causes a default library to be included at link-time.

If library *X* is something like `msvcrt`, then the dependency is likely coming from an external or third-party library that you're using, and the only practical way to avoid this is to add *X* to the "ignore specific library" option under project settings / linker / input.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed helpful.